# Application Insight Analytics Pivot

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

Is there a way to pivot in Azure Application insight analytic queries? SQL has a [Pivot Keyword](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), can similar be achieved in [Application insight Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference)?

When I run the below query I get exceptions and count, but I would like to see a day on day trending

```
exceptions 
| where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
| extend Api = replace(@"/(\d+)",@"/xxxx", operation_Name)
| summarize count() by type
| sort by count_ desc 
| limit 10
| project Exception = type, Count = count_
```

I am looking for something below day wise. [image]

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? There might be a different way to do this in Analytics

Comment: Thanks @EranG I have added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve something similar to what you need is by using:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp >= ago(7d)
| summarize count() by type, bin(timestamp, 1d)
```

This will give in the output one line per-type, per-day. Not exactly what you wanted but it will look good when rendered in graph (will give you a line for each type).

To get a table similar to what you put in your example would be more difficult, but this query should do the trick:

```
exceptions 
| where timestamp >= startofday(ago(3d)) 
| extend Api = replace(@"/(\d+)",@"/xxxx", operation_Name)
| summarize count() by type, bin(timestamp, 1d)
| summarize 
    Today = sumif(count_, timestamp == startofday(now())),
    Today_1 = sumif(count_, timestamp == startofday(ago(1d))),
    Today_2 = sumif(count_, timestamp == startofday(ago(2d))),
    Today_3 = sumif(count_, timestamp == startofday(ago(3d)))
    by type
```

Comment: This is not what I want, I need to build an HTML to send a mail and cannot use the graph. Is there any other way to convert rows to columns, any pointers or guidance will be helpful

Comment: I edited my answer to yield something like what you wanted